# how to make "grid note text view" using TextView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

im trying to make grid note view like this:

[grid note view sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDKPL.gif)

so i tried to make this using TextView.setLetterSpacing and Canvas.drawLine method

but not all characters(such as "." and "?", "/" etc) have the same width. (uppercase and lowercase too)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="AAAAAAAAaAaAaaAA.,A,A..A"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:letterSpacing="1"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i63WQ.png)

how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your simplest option is definitely using a monospace font, so all the characters *are* the same width. Other solutions (grid of individual 1-character `TextView`s, custom `View` or subclassed `EditText` etc.) will be way more work to set up, and get behaving the same way as what you already have.

You can use the basic Android monospace font:

```
android:fontFamily="monospace"
```

Or you could find a monospace font you like and [bundle it](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource), and use it the same way:

```
android:fontFamily="@font/my_cool_font"
```

[image: The finished, aligned layout with every character positioned in a fixed grid]

---

And since you're using *sp* for your font size, remember the text can scale based on the user's device preferences. So `letterSpacing` will need to shrink (or grow) depending on the adjusted text size, if you want the character positions to be consistent. Bigger characters = smaller spacing etc!

You'll need to do that in code, maybe in `onResume()` using something like this:

```
val fontScale = resources.displayMetrics.scaledDensity
editText.letterSpacing = 1 / fontScale
```

I don't know how consistent that will be, you'll have to investigate!